# Pausar um for para executar uma solicitação

Tags: javascript, jsf

Estou montando um questionário onde cada pergunta deve aparecer uma de cada vez na tela para o usuario e, assim que o usuário responder a mesma, ele deve seguir para a próxima pergunta.

Para isso estou usando um for para ir de pergunta em pergunta e uma função para montar a pergunta com as respostas possíveis conforme código abaixo:

```
for (let aux = 1; aux < nrPerguntas + 1; aux ++) {
    montaQuestionario(aux)
}
function montaQuestionario(aux) {
    pPergunta.innerHTML =  perguntas(aux)
    pEscala.innerHTML = ""
    for ( var i= 0; i < respostas.length ; i++) {
        pEscala.innerHTML = pEscala.innerHTML + `<td class="tdBorda" onclick="#"> ${respostas[i][1]} </td><td class="tdBranco"></td>`
    }
}
```

Meu problema é que o for vai da primeira a ultima pergunta sem pausar quando vai para a função montaQuestionario() e se colocar um break ele para de correr o for.

Existe alguma forma de fazer com que o for aguarde um retorno ou ação do usuário para continuar? Esta ação ficaria dentro da função já que seria ali que o usuário faria a seleção da resposta.

Comment: Ricardo, não está muito claro na pergunta que você quer. Se der uma editada acredito que fica mais fácil para conseguir resposta.

Comment: Bom dia, reescrevi a duvida, seja se ficou mais claro agora.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que uma maneira mais facil de fazer isso seria criar funções que essenciamente agiriam como um FOR mas so seriam chamadas quando necessarias.

```
    const botao_de_resposta = document.getElementById("idBotao");
    botao_de_resposta.addEventListener("click",responderPergunta);
    
    aux = 0;
    proximaPergunta(a)

    function responderPergunta() {
        //Logica para ver se a resposta esta certa
        //...

        aux++
        proximaPergunta(aux)
    }
    function proximaPergunta(a){
        pPergunta.innerHTML =  perguntas(a)
        //Poe a pergunta na tela
        //...
    }
```

Nesse caso ele checaria se a pergunta foi respondida e partiria para a próxima quando você clica no botão de responder, que eu presumo que você tenha no seu HTML.